# Getting scene normals in Unity

Tags: unity, shaders, graphics, normals

When I get the depthnormals with the shaderreplace script, it just replaces all the shaders in the scene and uses the meshes geometry to calculate the normals, ignoring the normalmap textures applied on them.

How can I get the final rendered scene normals to a rendertexture like it appears in the editor windows normal debug mode that is used for deferred light calculations and ambient occlusion and such ?

[image]

Comment: please explain more! why do you need get the final rendered scene normals.do you need shader?

Comment: I'll use it in a shader for post-processing.

Comment: first write shader for debugging normals then use ShaderReplacement for replacing normal map shader then Render it toTexture by RenderTexture .now you can use final result in RenderTexture.

Comment: Hmm.. depthnormals shouldn't ignore normal maps. Are you using custom shaders from which Unity might not be able to infer the normal maps itself? Is it an option for your project to switch to deferred rendering so the normals are already present in the GBuffer?

Comment: I'm using shader forge, there is an option for deferred or forward. Let me try getting everything rendered with deferred.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. Ive set up both the material shader and the camera to deferred, but replace shader don't have the option to read normalmaps. Is there a script I can use to make the camera render streight up depthnormals ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify how you're getting your normals currently? I'd assumed the shader replacement you were talking about was the automatic Unity process, but now it sounds like you're talking about manually replacing shaders via ShaderForge or scripts, so we might be solving different problems.

Comment: Edited the question to explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

[image: DisplayNormal]

you can use Replacement Shader to Displaying Mesh Normals

First attach this script to camera:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ReplacementShaderEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Shader ReplacementShader;


    void OnEnable()
    {
        if (ReplacementShader != null)
            GetComponent<Camera>().SetReplacementShader(ReplacementShader, "");
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        GetComponent<Camera>().ResetReplacementShader();
    }
}
```

then use this shader in above script for Replacing shaders

```
Shader "Tutorial/Display Normals" {
    SubShader {
        Pass {
    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma vertex vert
    #pragma fragment frag
    #include "UnityCG.cginc"
     
    struct v2f {
        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        float3 color : COLOR0;
    };
     
    v2f vert (appdata_base v)
    {
        v2f o;
        o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);
        o.color = v.normal * 0.5 + 0.5;
        return o;
    }
     
    half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
    {
        return half4 (i.color, 1);
    }
    ENDCG
     
        }
    }
    Fallback "VertexLit"
    }
```

In your comments you mentioned that you need store result to Rendertexture and use it in shader for post-processing

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CaptureMe : MonoBehaviour {
    public RenderTexture RT;
    public Camera SecondCamera;//Second Camera Renders Normal that store to RenderTexture
    public Shader shader;//shader that you want pass result to it

    void Update(){
    }

    void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source,RenderTexture target){

        int resWidth = Screen.width;
        int resHeight = Screen.height;

        RT = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
        SecondCamera.targetTexture = RT; //Create new renderTexture and assign to camera
        Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false); //Create new texture

        SecondCamera.Render();

        RenderTexture.active = RT;
        screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0); //Apply pixels from camera onto Texture2D

        SecondCamera.targetTexture = null;
        RenderTexture.active = null; //Clean


        Material mat = new Material(shader);

        mat.SetTexture ("_NormalScene", RT);

        Graphics.Blit (source, target,mat);


        Destroy(RT); //Free memory



    }
}
```

---

## Update

[image: DisplayNormal]

If you need better result you should be calculating the world normals.

```
Shader "Tutorial/DisplayNormal2"
{
    SubShader

    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct v2f

            {
                float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;

            };
            v2f vert(appdata_base v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv.xyz = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normal);
                return o;
            }
            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float3 c = i.uv.xyz;
                return float4(c, 1);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I said, that's not what I'm looking for. That method only displays the mesh normals, wheres I want to get the surface pixel normals.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ZW9v3O6.jpg

Comment: Like the image above is what replaceshader does. But instead I need the final rendered normals like below.

Comment: @CactusonFire here there is normal shader do you test it? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html

Comment: Yup, that's still the mesh normals.

Comment: @CactusonFire as you said you'll it use it in a shader for post-processing but why do you use post-processing word?!.do you need tool for exporting normal map?! please edit your question and add more detail

Comment: No, I'll use that normalmap as Rendertexture and feed it back to another shader to create a post-processing effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the gbuffers of the deferred rendering path

According to [this tutorial](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/rendering/part-15/).

You need to declare the samplers in your shaders:

```
sampler2D _CameraGBufferTexture0;
sampler2D _CameraGBufferTexture1;
sampler2D _CameraGBufferTexture2;
```

Then you can read from them like so

```
float3 albedo = tex2D(_CameraGBufferTexture0, uv).rgb;
float3 specularTint = tex2D(_CameraGBufferTexture1, uv).rgb;
float3 smoothness = tex2D(_CameraGBufferTexture1, uv).a;
float3 normal = tex2D(_CameraGBufferTexture2, uv).rgb * 2 - 1;
```

You're interested in `_CameraGBufferTexture2`